# How to share data between two closures, without global exposure?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, private

I have two closed scopes set up, in which one has a dependency on the other. Normally, I'd share data (in this case, a function with a prototype) by exposing it into the global scope, like so:

```javascript
(function(){

    var thing;

    /* ... */

    window.thing = thing;

}());
```

and:

```javascript
(function(){

    /* I now have access to 'thing' */

}());
```

Is there a pattern where data can be shared without exposing it to the entire window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be done by making the two closures themselves child scopes of another closure, and making the shared data a local variable within the parent closure:

```
(function() {

    var thing = 'foo';

    (function f1() {
        // thing is accessible here
        ...
    })();

    (function f2() {
        // and here!
        ...
    })();
})();
```

NB: closures are a *lexical* construct, that means the two functions must all be within the same source unit.

Comment: thing is not able to access inside f1()

Comment: @albertJegani yes it is!

Comment: (function f1() {
        // thing is accessible here
        ...
    })();
here 'thing' is not able access..

Comment: @albertJegani You're wrong.  Within the function `f1` the variable `thing` is most _certainly_ accessible.

Answer (score 1):

@Alnitak has provided a good solution for you problem.

But extending your example only , you can also do like this :

```
(function (xyz) {
      var thing = "foo";

      xyz.thing = thing;
}(closure1 = {}));
```

and then you can fetch like :

```
(function(){

    /* I now have access to 'thing' */
    alert(closure1.thing);
}());
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  You have read-only access to the value of `.thing` _as it was at the time of the assignment_.  If some other method modifies `thing` then `closure1.thing` does not provide access to that new value.